# Single query to check paired variables (Pre and Post) values in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, they are pre-checkup and post-checkup data. I have 60 odd variables that I need to check whether the values have changed or have stayed the same pre-checkup and post-checkup. Right now I am writing queries individually to check all the 60 variables:

```
select count(*) [Pre checkup],
       (select count(*)
        from Precheckup pre join
             Postcheckup post 
             on pre.VISIT_ID = post.VISIT_ID and
                pre.VEHICLE_REG_NO = post.VEHICLE_REG_NO
        where pre.COOLANT = 1 and post.COOLANT = 3
       ) [Post checkup]
from Precheckup
where COOLANT = 1
```

Output

```
Pre checkup      Post checkup
286              35

select count(*) [Pre checkup],
       (select count(*)
        from Precheckup pre join
             Postcheckuppost post
             on pre.VISIT_ID = post.VISIT_ID and
                pre.VEHICLE_REG_NO = post.VEHICLE_REG_NO
        where pre.BELTS_IDLERS = 1 and
              post.BELTS_IDLERS = 3
       ) [Post checkup]
from Precheckup
where BELTS_IDLERS = 1
```

OUTPUT

```
Pre checkup Post checkup
127         18
```

Table Format

```
CustID  Name  Number  COOLANT   BELTS_ILDERS    RADIATOR ...   ...[60 ODD SUCH COLUMNS]
```

I need my output in the following format:

```
COMPONENT        Pre-Checkup        Post-Checkup

COOLANT               286                 35
BELTS_IDLERS          127                 18
RADIATOR              112                 45
...                   ...                ...
...                   ...                ...
```

Is there a way that I can check for all 60 variables whose values were 1 during pre-checkup and whose values changed to 3 post-checkup in a single query?

I tried Gordon's query:

```
select v.var, count(v.preval),COUNT(v.postval)
from Precheckup pre join
 Postcheckup post
 on pre.VISIT_ID = post.VISIT_ID and
    pre.VEHICLE_REG_NO = post.VEHICLE_REG_NO cross apply
 (values ('Coolant', pre.coolant, post.coolant),
         ('Belt_idlers', pre.BELTS_IDLERS, post.BELTS_IDLERS)
         )
  v(var, preval, postval)                 
where v.preval = 1 and
  v.postval = 3
group by v.var,v.preval,v.postval;
```

I get below result.

```
var             (No column name)     (No column name)    
Belt_idlers          18                     18  
Coolant              35                     35
```

But It's not in the format that I want which is as below:

```
COMPONENT         Pre-Checkup        Post-Checkup

COOLANT               286                 35
BELTS_IDLERS          127                 18
RADIATOR              112                 45
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot the results using `apply`:

```
select v.var, count(*)
from Precheckup pre join
     Postcheckuppost post
     on pre.VISIT_ID = post.VISIT_ID and
        pre.VEHICLE_REG_NO = post.VEHICLE_REG_NO cross apply
     (values ('Coolant', pre.coolant, post.coolant),
             ('Belt_idlers', pre.Belt_idlers, post.Belt_idlers),
             . . .  -- list the variables here
     ) v(var, preval, postval)                 
where pre.preval = 1 and
      post.postval = 3
group by v.var;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try to generate and execute dynamic SQL. In this case it's important to exclude all columns, that are not items names:

```
-- Declarations
DECLARE 
    @stm nvarchar(max),
    @err int

-- Statement generation
SET @stm = N''
SELECT @stm = @stm +
        N'union all ' +
        N'select ' +
        [name] +
        N' AS Component, ' +
        N'count(*) [Pre checkup],
            (
            select count(*) from Precheckup pre 
            join Postcheckup post on pre.VISIT_ID = post.VISIT_ID and pre.VEHICLE_REG_NO = post.VEHICLE_REG_NO
            where pre.' +
        [name] +
        N' = 1 and post.' +
        [name] +
        N' = 3
        ) [Post checkup] 
        from Precheckup 
        where ' +
        [name] +
        N' = 1 
        group by ' +
        [name] + 
        N' '
FROM sys.columns
WHERE 
    (([name] <> 'CustID') AND ([name] <> 'Number') AND ([name] <> 'Name') AND ([name] <> 'VISIT_ID')AND ([name] <> 'VEHICLE_REG_NO')) AND
    (OBJECT_NAME([object_id]) = 'Precheckup')
SET @stm = STUFF(@stm, 1, 10, N'')

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stm
IF @err = 0 
    PRINT 'OK'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'Error'
```